# Unable to connect to airflow webserver [ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 8080)

Tags: python, airflow

Hi I am trying to connect airflow server through python but I am unable to connect.

```
pip install apache-airflow==2.0.2  
 !airflow db init
```

Now I am trying to connect to airflow server but I am getting an error message

```
!airflow webserver --port 8080
```

Error message

```
[2021-06-10 06:21:51,605] {providers_manager.py:299} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.cloud_sql.CloudSQLHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.mysql'
[2021-06-10 06:21:51,605] {providers_manager.py:299} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.cloud_sql.CloudSQLDatabaseHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.mysql'
[2021-06-10 06:21:51,606] {providers_manager.py:299} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.compute_ssh.ComputeEngineSSHHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'paramiko'
[2021-06-10 06:21:52,044] {providers_manager.py:299} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.cloud_sql.CloudSQLHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.mysql'
[2021-06-10 06:21:52,044] {providers_manager.py:299} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.cloud_sql.CloudSQLDatabaseHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.mysql'
[2021-06-10 06:21:52,045] {providers_manager.py:299} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.compute_ssh.ComputeEngineSSHHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'paramiko'
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/
[2021-06-10 06:21:52,073] {dagbag.py:451} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /dev/null
[2021-06-10 06:21:52,119] {manager.py:784} WARNING - No user yet created, use flask fab command to do it.
[2021-06-10 06:21:53,079] {providers_manager.py:299} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.cloud_sql.CloudSQLHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.mysql'
[2021-06-10 06:21:53,080] {providers_manager.py:299} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.cloud_sql.CloudSQLDatabaseHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.mysql'
[2021-06-10 06:21:53,081] {providers_manager.py:299} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.compute_ssh.ComputeEngineSSHHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'paramiko'
[2021-06-10 06:21:53,172] {providers_manager.py:299} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.cloud_sql.CloudSQLHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.mysql'
[2021-06-10 06:21:53,173] {providers_manager.py:299} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.cloud_sql.CloudSQLDatabaseHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.mysql'
[2021-06-10 06:21:53,173] {providers_manager.py:299} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.compute_ssh.ComputeEngineSSHHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'paramiko'
Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120
Logfiles: - -
Access Logformat: 
=================================================================            
[2021-06-10 06:21:55 +0000] [1204] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.10.0
[2021-06-10 06:21:55 +0000] [1204] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8080)
[2021-06-10 06:21:55 +0000] [1204] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-06-10 06:21:56 +0000] [1204] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8080)
[2021-06-10 06:21:56 +0000] [1204] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-06-10 06:21:57 +0000] [1204] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8080)
[2021-06-10 06:21:57 +0000] [1204] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-06-10 06:21:58 +0000] [1204] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8080)
[2021-06-10 06:21:58 +0000] [1204] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-06-10 06:21:59 +0000] [1204] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8080)
[2021-06-10 06:21:59 +0000] [1204] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-06-10 06:22:00 +0000] [1204] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 8080)
[2021-06-10 06:23:54,240] {webserver_command.py:217} ERROR - No response from gunicorn master within 120 seconds
[2021-06-10 06:23:54,240] {webserver_command.py:218} ERROR - Shutting down webserver
```

I tried killing the process in the port 8080using the following command

```
! freeport 8080
```

Still unable to connect airflow webserver.

Comment: Looks like something is listening to port 8080 already.

Comment: How do I connect to the server Kindly suggest @KlausD.

Comment: OK, a bit longer…You told the server to listen to port 8080. That port is already taken by some other process, either another instance of the server or some other program. You can a) end the process blocking the port or b) choose another port.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I also tried that I used port 8081 to test the instillation never ends @KlausD.

Comment: If you run webserver without -D flag (daemon) then the process will be blocking and will end only once you kill the webserver (to some error will occur)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Airflow: Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 8080)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45388141/airflow-cant-connect-to-0-0-0-0-8080)

Comment: no it does not answer @Vidya

Comment: I am not sure on which env you are trying this as you have not provided the details. Please make sure 8080 port is not occupied or use a different port. In my case, the airflow webserver instance was not killed properly and it was throwing the same error when I started the webserver. In the Linux platform, I checked using ps -ef | grep airflow command and  I killed the old airflow instances which resolved the error.

Comment: Hi thankyou for your response. I was running the codes on google colabs and even i fried up the port 8080 before i run the webserver even then no luck it not running and says port occupied @Vidya

Comment: Have you tried using a different port?

Comment: Yes but the installation in going in loops @floating_hammer